# How do i find if an object occurs twice in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I have a basic program that lets the user input items into a list. How do i check if an input has been put twice?

This is what i am starting with

```
a=input("")
a=a.title()
abilities=append(a)
```

I have got no further as i cannot find a solution

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: If you only care about finding if there are duplicates *after* you've added all the items to your list, you can try converting the list to a `set` and seeing if the size changes. Sets can't contain duplicates, so if the size shrinks, you know some duplicates were eliminated. You might also consider using a `set` directly, instead of the list, if you don't care about the order of the items it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the item is in the list like this:

```
if a in abilities:
    print("already in list")
else:
    abilities.append(a)
```

Also, fixes use of append.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=input("")
a=a.title()
abilities=append(a)
if abilities.count(a)>1 :
    print 'Your warning'
```